# Perl script messes with file descriptor in matlab

Tags: perl, matlab, io

I use a perl script for replacing some strings in a data file. The perl script is called from within a matlab program, which writes to the data file before the execution of the perl script and after it's execution.

My matlab program would then write to the data file, but for some reason it does not.

Here is a minimal example: 
Matlab code:

```
f = fopen('output.txt','a');
fprintf(f,'This is written\n');
perl('replace.perl','output.txt');
fprintf(f,'This is not\n');
[fname perm] = fopen(f)
type('output.txt');
fclose(f);
```

perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i
while(<>){
  s/This/This here/;
  print; 
}
close;
```

The variables fname and perm are correctly assigned. The output of `type` is only "This here is written".

I am quite new to perl and so I probably make some rookie mistake in the script that I can't find. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of `type` in this case? I don't know matlab but it seems like you are opening two copies of the file. What if you `open`, use `perl` to write/replace, `close`, then `open` again?

Comment: `type` will just display the file in this case. Yes closing the file after the perl script is done with it did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The secret is in the `-i`.  In-place editing in perl, and in many other programs, is accomplished by opening the original file for reading, opening a temp file for writing, then unlinking the original file and renaming the temp file to the original file's name.

Now after running your perl script, poor matlab is left holding a file handle to a now unlinked file.  You continue writing, but there's no easy way to see what was written...  Even if the file had not changed out from under matlab, you would have had to deal with the fact that matlab was about to write to a spot that would now no longer be the end of the file.

In the end, you need to be *very* careful of having two programs/users/computers writing to the same file at the same time.  Close the matlab file handle before calling perl.  Reopen it for appending later if that proves to be really necessary.

Comment: I am sorry ran out of time for edit: I just wanted to add here that I thought about it some more and found that I could also do the in-place editing using matlabs own `ftell()` and `fseek()` functionality while opening the file with `fopen('file','r+')`. This apperently changes the file from the position that `ftell()` returns byte by byte. Now I was wondering whether such a behaviour is advantageous, i.e. do I save time or memory this way? Is it applicable with some generality (UTF-16 or UTF-32)? Maybe someone knows some material not necessarily restricted to matlab for this question.

Comment: In place editing of files without a temp file is possible in any language with a `seek`. This thechnique is generally not used on text files, because to add or remove even a single byte requires that you read into memory and rewrite all the text after the chage.  You also spend more time with your file in an unstate.  Unicode encodings and `seek` can be interesting because the character to byte ratio is hard to predict.

Comment: Thanks again. Of course now I wonder what the applications of a `seek` are. It seems to be quite a clumsy function from your description.

Comment: It works wonderfully with fixed length records and other more structured files.  Text files... not so much.